# Give high-rep (but still < 10k) users extra voting on close

Tags: feature-request

How about letting users, somewhere around the 5-7k mark get 1.5 to 2 votes when voting to close, this lets fewer, (in theory) more trusted users deal with bad posts.

I'm mainly an SF denizen where there's only 7 10k users, this might not be as appropriate for SO.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this. Should these users be able to vote to close two times on the same question?

Comment: I'm saying these users votes should count more so fewer people need to vote, not that they would vote twice on the same question.

Comment: I can't speak for SF, but on SO, this would lead to chaos and madness. Madness, I tells ya! How about if stuff really needs to get closed & it ain't happening you flag for mod attention?

Comment: SU's got even fewer than SF, and i've been thinking the same thing, but really Fixed-Width is right.  flag for mod attention, and have patience -- eventually SU & SF will get to where SO is now, and questions that need closing will get closed.

Comment: "SU will get where SO is now?!" Seriously doubt it.

Answer (score 8):

I would just prefer that they increase the number of close votes you get per day for different Rep thresholds. Maybe 20 votes at 7k Rep and 30 votes at 10k Rep. I feel like I'm running out of close votes faster and faster every day trying to keep SO neat and tidy.

Perhaps certain close reasons shouldn't decrement your close vote count. For example, voting to migrate questions isn't really *closing* them, since they are still open on one of the other sites. I often use many of my close votes for duplicates, so I'd personally like it if those votes were basically free.

Keeping SO clean is hard. Let's go shopping! ;)

Comment: You have inspired me! I have just used all my close votes to get rid of unwanted questions!

Answer (score 2):

I definitely see the logic, but I kind of like the idea that we're all equal here. I've seen sites that give longer users tons more influence on voting and everything, and it makes me feel like I don't matter at all. :D

Comment: High-rep users have enough power already. I should know; I are one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in general bad questions are dealt with fine, the majority of them are closed very quickly (as in 5 - 10 minutes) from what I have seen. If there is a question that needs to be closed faster you should be using the `flag` button to draw a moderators attention to it.

The other issue is it makes the user interface more complex, which should be avoided. Rather than having the simple *Need 3 more votes to close*, it could end up *need 3.75 more votes to close* which makes no sense whatsoever.

The last issue is that, sure I have 10k rep on SO, but does that mean I should be trusted more? I have used the site, sure, but that doesn't mean I am always right. Requiring those 5 votes means that 5 people have to look over the question and decide *yes, this needs closing*

Answer (score 0):

Counting on SU: there are only **59** users with reputation above 3K who *can* vote on closing. Only **105** users have reputation above 2K (only 3 pages on the Users list).
Reduce the reputation requirements for voting on closing a question and for editing other peoples' posts.

Comment: Do you believe the moderators aren't fast enough closing question on SU? I thought we had a reputation for closing to quickly.

Comment: That's not my intention, Diago. But with a larger user base you won't have to close them yourselves. The community can help you closing and formatting question, leaving time for other moderator tasks.